# Gnome-sound-applet not detecting sound card

Tags: gnome, arch-linux, alsa, pulseaudio

Everything was working until today, the gnome-sound-applet does not detect any sound card. Alsamixer however is working and I can change volume.

I noticed that pulseaudio is not running and that start-pulseaudio-x11 gives me an error :

```
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
```

and

```
  lspci|grep Audio
```

gives

```
00:08.0 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 High Definition Audio (rev b1)
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the configuration file. pacman saved the configuration file as a pacnew, so I just renamed it.